# Solving inequalities in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve simple inequalities using matlab and got stuck.

```
solve(x^2>0,x)


ans = 
-1
1

solve(x^2>5,x)


ans = 
5^(1/2)+1
-5^(1/2)-1
```

which is totally wrong. What is the problem? My matlab version is R2014b.

Answer (score 0):

If you are solving an equation, e.g. `x^2 == 1`, then you are looking for specific *points*, i.e. the points `x=1` and `x=-1`. Luckily, MATLAB returns exactly this:

```
>> syms x
>> solve(x^2 == 1, x)
ans =
 -1
  1
```

Now, you are looking for solutions to an inequality. You really don't want to find all *points* for which the inequality holds, as this are infinitely many in your case. As stated in the documentation to [`solve`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html), the [`'ReturnConditions'`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#inputarg_ReturnConditions) flag will make `solve` return the *conditions* under which the (in-) equality holds.

```
>> syms x
>> S = solve(x^2>0,x, 'ReturnConditions', true)
>> S.conditions
ans =
 x < 0
 0 < x
```

or for the second example

```
>> syms x
>> S = solve(x^2 > 5, x,'ReturnConditions',true)
>> S.conditions
ans = 
  5^(1/2) < x
 x < -5^(1/2)
```